# Is it bad to generate temporary JWT token just to bypass [authorize] attribute for specific API call?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I am working on workflow approval web app using .NET core 2.1 as RESP API + AngularJS (version 1.x) as front-end. Normally, purchase order approver will need to login to get JSON Web Token (JWT) and navigate to specific order then click approve/reject button. Then, system will continue work with appropriate controller/action.

Note that the "Approve" controller is protected with [Authorize] attribute, but logged user will receive JWT to pass authentication. Everything work as expected now.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("login")]

public IActionResult Login([FromBody]User userSubmitted) {
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        // more token generation logic here ..
    var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    return Json(tokenString);
}
        
        
        
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]

[HttpPost("approve")]
public IActionResult Approve([FromBody] PurchaseOrder po) {
  // custom additional authentication logic here ..
  // approval/reject logic here ..
}
```

However, I want to provide a quick approval method by sending direct GET URL with predefined key e.g. https://www.example.com/api/quickapprove/key=xxx-difficult-to-guess-long-string-xxx to approver via email. This GET URL will fetch order data and display at front-end. Then approver will decide to click approve or reject button (which will call "Approve" API as normal). This way, approver can easily approve the order without going to the login page.

The problem is, once approver clicks approve/reject button, now the "Approve" controller/action will reject the HTTP request because there is no JWT/BEARER string sent together. What I plan to is generating a temporary JWT (like they login, but they didn't login actually) and attach it back when approver call "Approve" API.

Is this a bad idea? Any not-too-complicate but a better solution just to bypass [Authorize] attribute for specific API call time by time? Thank you.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/[controller]")]

[HttpGet("quickapprove")] 
public IActionResult QuickApprove([FromQuery] string key) {
  // getting details of request and display at front-end
  // getting details of request and display at front-end
  
  // I plan to generate temporary JWT for later use here !!
  // I plan to generate temporary JWT for later use here !!
}
```

Comment: Generating temporary JWT is a solution but not recommended. If we can access with [Authorize] attribute for specific API, there is meaningless of the [Authorize]. Everyone can hack with that specific API. In my opinion you could reconsider your authorization mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another API endpoint for approving with URL, and create an Base64 Uniqe Code for the request should be approved which contains encrypted user id and any details you need, then decode then decrypt and call this API Anonymous.